# How to put width value as percentage in storyboard animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a drawer using storyboard.
There are 2 child grids in the base grid.
One is a 'MenuGrid', the other is a 'ContentGrid'.

[image]

So I wrote a storyboard like this(This is a storyboard that adjusts the width of the 'MenuGrid'.):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuOpen">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="MenuGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="300"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuClose" >
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="MenuGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="300"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="60"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonOpenMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonCloseMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Width="300" x:Name="MenuGrid" Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonCloseMenu" Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonOpenMenu" Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" >
                </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Column="1">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Every time I press a certain button it works very well.
However, when the Width of the MenuGrid decreases, I want the Width of the ContentGrid to increase as well.

In EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="300", is there a way to express 'Value' as a percentage or ratio rather than an int value?

Comment: Simply set first column definition `Width="Auto"`, since you are animating its child width it will follow.